# Transfer Message in C++ to Java with RabbitMq

Tags: java, c++, message-queue, transfer, data-transfer

I have standard Send and Recv files written in Java for RMQ found below.
I've modified the code a little bit so that it stores the message into a variable.

Right now the message is a String that I just type up but I want to be able to take data (probably an init32 variable) from a C++ program and pass that into my storedMessage variable.

Recv File

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*; 
import java.io.IOException;

public class Recv 
{
    public static String recv(String ip, String Q) throws Exception 
    {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(ip);
        factory.setUsername("test");
        factory.setPassword("test");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
        MyConsumer consumer=new MyConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume(Q,true,consumer);

        return consumer.getStoredMessage();
    }

    public static class MyConsumer extends DefaultConsumer 
    {
        public String storedMessage;

        public MyConsumer(Channel channel) 
        {
            super(channel);
        }

        public String getStoredMessage() 
        {
            return storedMessage;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
            throws IOException 
        {
            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
            storedMessage = message; // store message here
        }
    }
}
```

Send file

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;   
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class Send {

    public static void send(String ip, String Q) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

        //set connection info
        factory.setHost(ip);
        factory.setUsername("test");
        factory.setPassword("test");

        //create connection
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();

        //create channel
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        //publish message
        int a = 1; 
        while (a!=0)
        {
            channel.queueDeclare(Q, false, false, false, null);
            for(int i=1; i<=2; i++)
            {
                String message = "Pizza #"+i;
                channel.basicPublish("", Q, null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'" + Q);
            }

            a--;
        }

        //SHUT IT ALL DOWN!
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```